# How to use Laravel routes over react router

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel

I integrated React in my laravel project. I started off using the react router but now I would like to switch back to Laravel routes.

**Is it possible to inject my react components globally in my blade files just like Vue?**

For setting up React routing I used following wildcard:

```
Route::view('/{path?}', 'layouts.app');
```

When I try to get back to normal laravel routing I get the following error

**Error**

> Uncaught Error: Target container is not a DOM element.

**My web.php**

```
Route::get('/', 'PageController@index');
```

**Controller**

```
class PageController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('layouts.index');
    }
}
```

**Layouts.app file**

```
<body>
    <div class="main">
        @section('content')
    </div>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/test.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
</body>
```

**Index.blade**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<Call> </Call>
@endsection
```

**React**

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import Header from './Header'
import Call from './Call'
import Recipient from './Recipient';
import Avatar from './Avatar';
import registerServiceWorker from '../registerServiceWorker';

class App extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
          <Header />
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' component={Call} />
            <Route exact path='/rusthuis' component={Recipient} />
            <Route exact path='/avatar' component={Avatar} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
registerServiceWorker();
```

Answer (score 1):

The target container is not a DOM element because in your HTML you don't have a `div` with the id of `app`.

You should change your html to this for `layouts.app`:

```
<body>
    <div id="app" class="main">
        @section('content')
    </div>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/test.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

By default Laravel(6) already is utilizing `id="app"` so in your react index.blade.php, i.e. where you define your react entry point, use a different id name to prevent react **App.js** from overriding your normal Laravel files i.e:

**index.blade.php**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        
        <!-- csrf token -->
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

        <!-- styles -->
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="app-react"></div>
        <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./Home";
function App() {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Navbar />
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Home}></Route>
                <Route component={Default}></Route>
            </Switch>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}

export default App;

if (document.getElementById("app-react")) {
    ReactDOM.render(
        <Router>
            <App />
        </Router>,
        document.getElementById("app-react")
    );
}
```

**using  the following route**

```
Route::get('/{path?}',function(){
    return view('app');
});
```

`{path?}` represent anything(word)

The first level URLs will affect the react but higher levels i.e

```
Route::view('/user/links','bladefile')
```

Links in our case will be a legit Laravel route.

Answer (score 0):

put your

```
Route::view('/{path?}', 'layouts.app');
```

at end of web routes so that it will be loaded at last getting your all views